# Route for resetting password in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am using the custom password reset option in Laravel 7. When the user clicks the reset password button (in the inbox of her/his email), the user is redirected to the password reset link. Here is my link

`http://localhost/LaraTest/public/reset/5199667639cfc4f5ea624f4c18dbf7e8-vJcnLSH92vAj1IlnV3j7phT8zBtcbX0gSDbjXX37oFsuEM560oAiehZ4oVd0?email=basish%40gmail.com`

Here is the code which generates the link

```
$token1=   md5($fp_email);
    $token2 =   Str::random(60);
    $fp_token = $token1."-".$token2;
//some more codes here
$link = 'localhost/LaraTest/public/reset/' . $fp_token . '?email=' . urlencode($fp_email);

//$link is sent to user as email
```

**Route (after some research)**

```
Route::get('reset/{tokenname}{email}','LoginController@resetpassword');
```

**Controller**

```
public function resetpassword(Request $request){
     
     return view('resetpassword');
     
}
```

1. How would I define my route? I am a bit confused  as my link contains
   both the **password reset token** and the **email id**.
2. How will I retrieve the **password reset token** and the **email id** from the link above,after being redirected to the *new password form*?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul I haven't. because I have no clue

Comment: otherwise, I would have mentioned in the question itself

Comment: Instead of showing us how you generate that link (which I assume works) why not show us what you've tried so far in defining the route? You probably can access the email paramter from `$request->email` within that route and use that to get the user along with their password reset tokens. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @KamleshPaul I updated my answer with `routes` and `controller`

Comment: @apokryfos I updated my answer with `routes` and `controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route should be:

```
Route::get('reset/{tokenname}','LoginController@resetpassword');
```

In then the actual handler:

```
public function resetpassword(Request $request, $token){     
     $email = $request->email;
     return view('resetpassword', compact('token', 'email');    
}
```

Then in your view you can have:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{$email}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{$token}}" />
```

and your actual password reset handler this would probably be defined in a route like:

```
Route::post('reset', 'LoginController@doPasswordReset');
```

and the method body would be (code borrowed in some part from the [laravel source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L38)):

```
public function doPasswordReset(Request $request){   
     $validatedRequest = $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        ]);  
     $email = $request->email;
     $token = $request->token;
     $broker = app(PasswordBrokerManager::class);
     
     $response = $broker()->reset(
            $validatedRequest, function ($user, $password) {
                 // save new password here
            }
        );

        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? // Reset response?
                    : // Reset failed response?
}
```

This will ensure Laravel can verify the user by the provided email and password before doing the actual password reset.

Comment: I understood now. The token value is `5199667639cfc4f5ea624f4c18dbf7e8-vJcnLSH92vAj1IlnV3j7phT8zBtcbX0gSDbjXX37oFsuEM560oAiehZ4oVd0?email=basish%40gmail.com`. I wanted to separate the token and email like this **token** =*5199667639cfc4f5ea624f4c18dbf7e8-vJcnLSH92vAj1IlnV3j7phT8zBtcbX0gSDbjXX37oFsuEM560oAiehZ4oVd0* and **email** = basish%40gmail.com